# Second datasource in spring application.properties for tests?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, integration-testing, hsqldb

I have datasource defined in my `application.properties` as **Oracle** database and that's ok, the controller & repository work fine, I can persist entities and fetch database records.

I have integration tests written. Before I connected my app with database I created some objects and persisted them in `@PostConstruct` method - and that was ok. But now, when I connected everything with database, my tests try to fetch records from the table which is pretty large.
I think that's due to my `application.properties` file in which defined datasource is Oracle database.

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@blabla
spring.datasource.username=blabla
spring.datasource.password=blabla
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
```

I want to carry on tests using some in-memory **HSQL**, not real database. But I still want my controller and repository to use the real one. How can I do it? Is there any possibility to add second datasource in application.properties? Or maybe an easier solution?

Comment: What build tool are you using?

Comment: this is spring boot app

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 4 you have `@Profile` annotation so you can use its advantage.
Create another like `application-test.properties` file with it's own properties.

Create configuration for your tests:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test") 
public class TestConfiguration {
    ....
}
```

Then annotate your class with `@ActiveProfiles` annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestRepository {
   ...
}
```

Comment: What exactly should be in TestConfiguration class? Now i have no configuration, only @Before method which saves objects using repository methods. I use Rest Assured to test my controller.

Comment: Are you by any possibility using Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, this is Spring Boot application

Comment: So @ActiveProfiles [above my test class] reffering to application-test.properties is enough? Seems nice, but I got no idea how to configure hsqldb there to be used properly.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this, one way is to use Spring profiles. The test profile would use a different properties file than the production one.

Comment: What about my entity class which is linked to the oracle table via @Table annotation? It must be used in controller/repository as well as tests.

Comment: Your test database would have similar tables as the real database, but empty (or more likely some test data).

Answer (score 0):

Spring has `org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder` package that allows you to bind the dataSource programatically.

**Sample Test class that I use:**

```
public class MockJNDIContext {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {

        SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = SimpleNamingContextBuilder.emptyActivatedContextBuilder();
        OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();//Use your own Connection Pool DS here as you require
        ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.xxx.xxx.xx:9999:SID");
        ds.setUser("USER");
        ds.setPassword("PASSWORD");
        //Bind it to the JNDI you need
        builder.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/MY/APP", ds);

    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("JNDI Initialized");
    }

}
```

**Suite Class:**

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        MockJNDIContext.class,
        InitializeTestConfig.class
})
public class ServiceSuite{
}
```

May be this helps? If you are trying to load from one more application.props, use one more class (`InitializeTestConfig.class`) that initializes and passes the DS args and add to suite as mentioned above and try?