# Spring-Data, Same Entities, Different Database

Tags: java, spring

Is the following possible with **Spring-Data**?

- I have 2 Databases (Deploy, Test).
- I have one set of Entities.
- A programm needs to swith between the 2 databases multiple times, with
  the same entities.

Example:
I have a Table FOO with an mathing Entity Foo.

**Now i would like to be able to do the following:**

- Deploy-Database: read something from Foo
- Test-Database: read something from foo
- Do something with Foo
- Deploy-Database: write something to Foo
- Test-Database: write something to Foo

Thanks for your help

Comment: *Why* should the same run of the program be doing that? The whole point of having a test database is to isolate it from your production database in case something goes wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984604/second-datasource-in-spring-application-properties-for-tests Maybe reading this could be helpful...

Comment: Dont hang to phrasings. You can name the DBS DB1 and DB2.